# Modify product attribute programmatically in Magento2 (2.1.0)

Tags: magento2, product, attributes

I'm trying to fix product descriptions, therefore i try to iterate through a collection and then save it.

But got exception here:

> [ReflectionException]
>   Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Media does not
>   exist

```
use Magento\Framework\App\State;

use \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;


class CollectionFixCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $productFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    protected $productModel;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;


    public function __construct(
        ProductFactory $productFactory,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        ObjectManagerInterface $manager,
        ProductRepository $productRepository,
        State $state
    )
    {
        $state->setAreaCode('admin');
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->objectManager = $manager;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;

        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('collection:fix')->setDescription('Fixes product collection');
    }


    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, Outputinterface $output)
    {
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addFieldToSelect('*');

        foreach ($collection->getItems() as $product)
        {
            $description = $product->getData('description');

            //modifies description here

            $product->setData('description', $description);

            try{
                $this->productRepository->save($product);
            } catch(Exception $e){
                $output->writeln($e->getMessage());
            }
//          [ReflectionException]                                                       
//           Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Media does not exist 
        }

//      try{
//          $collection->save();
//      } catch(Exception $e){
//          $output->writeln($e->getMessage());

//      [ReflectionException]                                                       
//      Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Media does not exist 
//      }
    }
}
```

Any ideas anyone?

Full stack trace:

```
Exception trace:
 () at /vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19
 ReflectionClass->__construct() at /vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19
 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() at /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:44
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters() at /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:71
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:57
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() at /vendor/magento/framework/Validator/UniversalFactory.php:36
 Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory->create() at /vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/AbstractAttribute.php:498
 Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute->getBackend() at /var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Eav/Attribute/Interceptor.php:1103
 Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor->getBackend() at /vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/ResourceModel/ReadHandler.php:139
 Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\ReadHandler->execute() at /vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Read/ReadAttributes.php:59
 Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Read\ReadAttributes->execute() at /vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Read.php:116
 Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Read->execute() at /vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EntityManager.php:61
 Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager->load() at /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product.php:655
 Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product->load() at /var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Interceptor.php:258
 Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->load() at /vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php:531
 Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->load() at /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:146
 Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor->___callPlugins() at /var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Interceptor.php:2301
 Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor->load() at /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php:220
 Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository->get() at /var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Model/ProductRepository/Interceptor.php:24
 Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor->get() at /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php:493
 Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository->save() at /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:74
 Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor->___callParent() at /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php:70
 Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext() at /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php:63
 Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}() at /vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Plugin/AroundProductRepositorySave.php:62
 Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Plugin\AroundProductRepositorySave->aroundSave() at /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php:67
 Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext() at /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138
 Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() at /vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/Plugin/AroundProductRepositorySave.php:74
 Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Plugin\AroundProductRepositorySave->aroundSave() at /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:142
 Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor->___callPlugins() at /var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Model/ProductRepository/Interceptor.php:52
 Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor->save() at /src/Aqio/PMT/Console/Command/CollectionFixCommand.php:89
 Aqio\PMT\Console\Command\CollectionFixCommand->execute() at /vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:257
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:96
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /bin/magento:23
```

Comment: Although it is a late comment, have you checked clearing generated/code?

Answer (score 5):

The solution:

```
$product->setData('description', $description);
try{
    $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'description');
} catch(Exception $e){
    $output->writeln($e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use ProductRepositiry to save the product.

Save method in product model is deprecated and collection save method  just iterate by item and call save method for them

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but i've got the exact same error there...
Just added the whole code above!

Comment: it's strange, can you post the full stack trace?  (for command line add -vvv)

Comment: you can find the full stack trace above!

Comment: Just made a fresh install of 2.1.0 because upgrade from 2.0.7 to 2.1.0 broke too much stuff. Had some issues now with required attributes, just removed the requirement for testing purpose. And now i'm getting [Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException]  
  Requested product doesn't exist

Comment: It' looks like bug, can you create issue on github?

Comment: Sure, i will open a ticket there.

Comment: I did, but no one is answering

Comment: No one's answering, but i seem to have fixed another issue, because now i get this error message: 

[Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException]  
  Unable to save product (from Magento/Catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php line549)

Comment: have a look here please https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5414
@KAndy

Comment: The solution can be found there now. It's the same fast way as it was before in Magento...